# How do I set the logging level for HikariCP?

Tags: java, jdbc, log4j, slf4j, hikaricp

Currently, HikariCP is logging at level `INFO` and I want to set it to `SEVERE`. When I try to set the level on the parent logger (the only reference to logging I can find) it throws the error:

```
dataSource.getParentLogger().setLevel( Level.SEVERE );
```

The error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getParentLogger(HikariDataSource.java:176)
```

How do I properly set the logging level?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*HikariCP* uses *slf4j* under the hood. You will have to set the log level on your actual logger implementation (*logback*, *log4j*, *JUL*, ...).

Also, *slf4j* provides a very simple logger implementation *slf4j-simple*. Just add the dependency to your *pom*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

You can then configure it using [system properties](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html), e.g.

```
java -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.com.zaxxer.hikari=error ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way to programmatically set log level

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;

ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger hikariLogger = (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.zaxxer.hikari");
hikariLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR);
```

Comment: thanks for this, no other suggestions work

Answer (score -8):

Remove theese jars from your classpath or lib directory if you have.

logback-classic.jar logback-core.jar