# Disable hikari pool in development environment

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

In development environment, `spring boot with hikari`, jdbc connection is unstable, if idle for some time, then call api again, it will fail(guess the network unstable cause it, because in production environment is ok)

```
2022-03-08 12:13:35.571 [http-nio-9090-exec-6] WARN  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@72415749 (No operations allowed after connection closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.

### The error occurred while executing a query
### Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30038ms.] with root cause
com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ConnectionIsClosedException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.checkClosed(NativeSession.java:1209)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:567)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setNetworkTimeout(ConnectionImpl.java:2484)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.setNetworkTimeout(PoolBase.java:550)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.isConnectionAlive(PoolBase.java:165)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:179)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:155)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:157)
```

but next time it will ok.

Because it is development environment, no performance requirements, so I want to disable connection pool, that is every time use connection just create a new connection.

SO how to config `spring.datasource.hikari.XXX` to disable connection pool and create new jdbc connection every time when use?

Comment: Your question has an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70075677/1845404) already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use different [datasource](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/17125) as `SimpleDriverDataSource`

> as of Spring Boot 2.3.x, the following works out of the box with no need to exclude anything:

> ```
> spring.datasource.type=org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource
> ```

Also you can check MySQL [recommended settings](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/MySQL-Configuration)